# How to query for posts without a post_format

Tags: wp-query, post-formats

I have looked in the WP codex for an example which shows how to use a taxonomy query to retrieve a set of posts that have no post_format.

IOW: 'All posts where an aside or quote or link...etc... post_format has not been assigned; eg. a 'standard' post_format.'

But I can't seem to figure out how to query for posts that have -no- post_format.

IOW: it seems as though if the post has no post_format (eg. 'aside' or 'quote') it returns an empty result in get_post_format()

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array(?????)
     )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How does one set up this kind of query?

Answer (score 2):

You have to query post that has no post format attached:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
      'terms' => get_terms('post_format')
    )
  )
);
```

To improve performance you can hardcoding the post format instead of using `get_terms` to retrieve them:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
      'terms' => array('post_format-aside','post_format-chat','post_format-gallery','post_format-link','post_format-image','post_format-quote','post_format-status','post_format-video','post_format-audio')
    )
  )
);
```

---

**Edit**

Once you ask for it in comments, I'll give you the raw SQL query that can perform same task. Please note that once post *without* post format are not stored anywhere (standard post format means *no* post format), to obtain what you want you need to nest 2 queries with the nested containing a join among 3 tables.
This is very far from what you can call a *performant* query. For this it's a good idea cache the result in a transient:

```
function post_without_formats() {
    $cached = get_transient('post_without_formats');
    if ( $cached ) return $cached;
    global $wpdb;
    $post_without_format = $wpdb->get_results(
      "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'
       AND post_type = 'post' AND ID NOT IN (
         SELECT p.ID FROM $wpdb->posts as p
         LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
         LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
         WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post'
         AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_format'
         GROUP BY p.ID
       )"
    );
    set_transient('post_without_formats', $post_without_format);
    return $post_without_format;
}

function reset_post_without_formats($term, $taxonomy) {
  if ( $taxonomy == 'post_format' ) {
    delete_transient('post_without_formats');
    post_without_formats();
  }
}

add_action('edited_term_taxonomy', 'reset_post_without_formats', 99, 2);
```

As you can see I reset the transient everytime a post format is added or removed from a post. This will slow down a bit your backend but will increase the frontend speed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some testing and report back. I prefer #1--even though it's slower, simply because those options will certainly be expanded over time. I still think there should be a faster solution that uses a direct SQL statement... just can't figure out what it is. Best.

Comment: @jchwebdev `get_terms` is more or less a wrapper for a SQL query.. an **most important** it use **cache**, direct SQL don't... so, SQL query will **not** be faster. After that I'm not so sure post format terms will be expanded, they are are just taxonomy terms, the only reason why there's a sense to their existence is to give a *restricted* number of taxonomy terms sharing same slug among all the thousand themes that exists for WP. If this number of terms become too large I think post format become useless.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but it seems to me that there must be a relation to the taxonomy table to get the terms, so it should be possible to do something like a JOIN which shows all posts which return NULL for that join. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all the hard work. I'll report back as soon as I have a moment to play with it. Best. ---JC